# Knowing Class Hierarchy in the project solution following MVC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, hierarchy

I have been given two applications : One in which functionality is already implemented but analysis is required to know how it was implemented and the other application in which functionality has to be implemented.

Both applications follow MVC architecture and have different libraries also. I need to know the class hierarchy (considering all layers) in my both the applications.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, but not have the architecture functionality in it.

My Approach : Once i will be able to find the class hierarchy in the application then i can take one small module of the application and analyse that module to check for implemented functionality.

**Question : How to get class hierarchy considering all layers?**